# Is there any way around storing form values in window.localstorage if you wnt the data to be there if the page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html

I'm just wondering if there is any way around storing form values in window.localstorage if you wnt the data to be there if the page is refreshed?

Seems like creating a variable for all form values and then assigning them to a session then reloading them again might be the hard way of doing this? is ther another way? Im using django

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in a session cookie. You can then read the cookie when the page is refreshed.

to Write a cookie in javascript:

```
    document.cookie="username=John Doe";
```

to read a cookie in javascript:

```
    var x = document.cookie;
```